# Amazon Product API - Checkout

Tags: amazon-web-services, checkout, payment-processing, amazon-product-api

Is it possible to checkout directly on my website using Amazon checkout (or another checkout such as paypal), without being redirected to the Amazon website?

Answer (score 1):

In Amazon Checkout you will  have to finish your shopping at Amazon.com, but if you want to use Paypal they have APIs that you can use to finish checkout on your site
http://blog.effectlabs.com/post/2011/11/07/Paypal-Express-Checkout-with-C-using-Paypal-web-services.aspx

can download sample code at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Product Advertising API [allows you to create shopping carts remotely](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/CHAP_PurchasingtheItemsinaRemoteShoppingCart.html) but you'll have to finish your shopping at Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, it is not possible to finish checkout on your site, because the product that  is being purchased is sold by a merchant on Amazon.com marketplace and it will not allow checkout outside Amazon.com.